# Define an enum in Grails 3.1.1

Tags: grails, enums

Can you please let me know where to define an `enum` in Grails 3? In Grails 2 we can define them in `src/groovy`, but I m not getting any ideas where to define `enum` in Grails 3. Because they are not working with `src/groovy` in Grails 3.

Answer (score 2):

They will work in `src/groovy/` in Grails 3 if you configure the build to know about that source directory but the more typical thing would be to define them under `src/main/groovy/`.